# Converting a string to binary?

Tags: java

Okay, A friend helped me with this code a little bit. I understand what everything else does and why it does it except for one thing. Where is this 128 coming from?? Also, this program runs, pulls the string from the file, converts it to binary, but takes all of the spaces out, so that when you re convert the binary back to the string, it is all one word. So what is the 128 and what can I do to keep the spaces?

/*********************************************************
 *I fixed it, Thanks for your help guys!                 *
 *I have changed the code so you can see how I fixed it. *
 *********************************************************/

```
         public static void main(String[] args) {

          String text = "My string to binary works too";

          byte[] bytes = text.getBytes();
          StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

          for (byte b : bytes){
            int val = b;
          for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            binary.insert(0, (val & 1) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val >>>= 1;
          }
            binary.insert(0, ' ');
         System.out.print(binary);
      }



      }
```

}

Comment: Highest binary value is 128...! So it might come

Comment: Highest binary value is not 128??

Comment: the highes slot value in a byte is 128. but i dont understand what the 128 is doing here

Comment: Re your question about keeping the spaces, are you talking about the spaces between the binary bytes in your output or the spaces between words in the original text?  Note that an ASCII space in binary is 0010000 so you should see some of those in your binary output.

Comment: @Turix `next()` from `Scanner` using whitespace as a delimiter, which is why he's losing the spaces.

Comment: The spaces in the text after you reconvert the binary that is printed here back into a string. So for "Joey is an idiot for using .next" it would give me the binary, then if i converted that binary back to text with a working binary to text, it will read "Joeyisanidiotforusing.next"

Comment: @SteveP. Ah ha.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Now I get what he was asking.

Comment: So what could i do to eliminate that issue? ( the .next() issue that is)

Comment: If you couldn't tell, i am a newer programmer. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, 128 is just a bit mask of 1 in the MSB.

Following the logic through if you have a byte that is 10011001:

```
10011001 & 10000000 = 10000000 != 0
11011001 << 1 = 00110010
00110010 & 10000000 = 00000000 == 0

and so on...
```

Here's alternative logic that achieves the same thing but reversed (mask in the LSB) and perhaps makes more immediate sense:

```
int val = b;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    binary.insert(0, (val & 1) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    val >>>= 1;
}
binary.insert(0, ' ');
```

Following this logic through you have:

```
10011001 & 00000001 = 00000001 != 0
11011001 >>> 1 = 01101100
01101100 & 00000001 = 00000000 == 0

and so on...
```

Comment: You're welcome. : ) Although I understand the use of 128, using 1 makes more sense to me and works for any word length. 128 only works for a byte.

Comment: Instead of iserting a space someone could recommend not to use Scanner altogether. InputStream is there exactly for this.

Comment: @Basilevs Yeah it's true InputStream is a more direct approach. Using raw FileInputStream would also negate the need for a String being read at all since the OP could just directly use the bytes from the read.

Answer (score 1):

128 is 2^7 power, which means in binary it is 10000000.  Bytes consist of 8 bits.  So on the line where the 128 is being used, you are doing a bitwise AND to get the highest bit.  (Then on the next line, you shift the value to one bit to the left and repeat, so you successively get each bit value from left to right.)

Comment: Okay, that makes total sense. Thanks

Comment: What about byte's sign?

Comment: @Joey For reference, you lose the spaces because you're using `next()` from `Scanner`, which uses white-space as a delimiter.

Comment: Dont understand what you are trying to ask here??

Comment: AH okay, darn. Thank you. I completely over looked that.

Comment: @Basilevs The most significant bit of a number is the sign bit (usually). But in this case, he is just converting characters to binary bytes, not trying to get a numeric value for them.  (And assuming he's working with ASCII characters, the most significant bit will always be 0 anyway.)

Comment: Or not? Where the sign goes if the 128 is the MSB? Moreover the question states that reverse conversion should be possible, so getting value without losing bits important. Assumptions about ASCII smell bad nowadays too.

Comment: @Basilevs To be clear, his code will work (that is, print the correct binary representations of the characters) whether they are ASCII or not, irrespective of the signed/unsigned status of the bytes.

Comment: 128 = 10 000 000, this number [can't be fit in a byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). All bit matching is done in integer space here.

Comment: @Basilevs A byte is 8 bits which means it can hold binary 10000000 just fine.

Comment: Its 8 bits, but its signed. Therefore the value 10000000 is actually -128.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40059/discussion-between-basilevs-and-turix)

Comment: @Basilevs It's 10000000 no matter whether you interpret the value as 128 or -127 (note, not -128).  It still fits in a byte and the code still prints out 10000000.

Comment: @Basilevs -127 will not give you the right & because -127 is not 10000000 for an int. 128 is the correct number. Of course all the logic is done as ints. No bits are lost, I don't understand the issue. It sounds like you think the sign bit disappears or something.

Comment: @Basilevs Just commenting here to acknowledge that you were right (after our chat).  My original answer was missing a '0' in the binary representation due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The 128 is an 1000 0000 in binary, so it is the most significant bit (MSB) of byte. MSB is the fisrt bit from the left. Since the code prints bits from MSB to LSB, the every loop iteration prints 1 or 0 depending on result of AND (&) with value having only MSB bit setted (128), and shifts value to left by one bit.